# Can't use the OWM maps in leaflet.js without exposing my API keys over express.js server

Tags: html, node.js, express, leaflet, cross-browser

I wanted to create a Node.js application that required me to fetch data from APIs(geocoding for coordinates and OpenWeatherMap for weather). I completed it with success and wanted to extend the functionality of it by implementing the maps API from OWM as given here (https://openweathermap.org/api/weathermaps). I used the leaflet.js to including tiling. The basic method works fine, the search works, the coordinates and weather are properly displayed, the partials/views implementations using handlebars(hbs - https://www.npmjs.com/package/hbs) works fine too.

But, then I included the weather map overlay using maps.hbs. This maps.hbs(included media) is a partial hbs file which contains the code for fetching maps and temperature overlay(something like this). I did it and it just worked fine, but only statically, how do I implement it dynamically?

The index.hbs is the landing page which opens up on server, I created a partial for my map and included it in
[index.hbs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HJKD.png)

The only thing exposed to general user is the PUBLIC folder, for which i used express.js. I stored the API calls inside src/utils to prevent directly sending the script which includes my API keys. The samesite security policy also is disallowing me the usage. How do I dynamically ask the user for a city to display the maps.(I have successfully addad the coordinates and weather fetching, but this is weirdly difficult). If I try to put the code inside a file and then include in maps.hbs. It gives an error that

`L.map[.....], L is undefined`

[maps.hbs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zW566.png)

maybe because it couldn't access the script in the header to create an object named L. How do I solve this problem? Please ask if there needs some clarification over the implementation.

See this for front-end [index.hbs on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7XJ5.png).

I am thinking of two possible ways, add if any other one is possible.

1. A hack is to ask the user for OWM api keys themselves and then load the maps(which defeats the point of having it for portfolio showcase).
2. Instead of directly accessing the script inside map.hbs partial exposed to index.hbs, is there a way to implement it without exposing the keys, just like I did in the weather and coordinates API calls. But again using this method, I can't access the L object provided by script, and if I include both script insertion and calls, then APIs are exposed directly through partial.